# Black screen in Ubuntu 21.10 after changing resolution in Wayland

Tags: display-resolution, wayland, 21.10

I recently updated to Ubuntu 21.10. I changed the resolution and my screen went black. Now whenever I log in it shows that black screen(the black screen dosen't appear in login screen, but after I login). This seems to happen only on Wayland, if I choose Xorg when logging in it works fine. I think everything works, its just that I can't see anything. I opened terminal using ctrl+alt+t and rebooted the system using sudo reboot(after logging in) and it worked fine. So it seems to be responding but theres black screen.

Here's what I have tried:

Reseting gnome using `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`
Opening terminal in login screen using ctrl+alt+f5 and changing the resoltuion using command line.

**I don't know if these things are relevant, but I'll mention them anyways:**

I dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 11

System specs:-

AMD Ryzen 7 3700u

8gb ram

AMD® Radeon(tm) vega 10 graphics

512gb storage(ssd)

Comment: Linux is free when your time has no value (I had to write it, sorry). The bug seems to be fixed in 5.13.0-28 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1947453, workaround (not checked by me): amdgpu.dc=0 boot kernel option.

Comment: Tbh it barely wasted any of my time since i mainly use xorg. I asked to know what the problem was, just in case if it ever happened on xorg. Thanks for the workaround though! Can't test it since i have reinstalled Ubuntu and that problem is no more, and doesn't seem to happen anymore

Answer (score 0):

From your login screen enter the command-line interface by pressing ctrl+alt+F2. Then open the file ~/.config/monitors.xml using command:
`nano ~/.config/monitors.xml`
Now change the width, height and rate according to your requirement and then reboot.
If this doesn't works then just delete the file ~/.config/monitors.xml and reboot.
The first solution worked for me.